# How can I reduce this code with the DRY principle?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dry

I am practicing the **DRY** principle in my R code and I have reached this point where I have not managed to reduce the amount of lines of code. I see that it is very repetitive and I would like your help.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2023)

# first, I generate the data
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  replicate(10, sample(0:1, 7, replace = TRUE)),
  replicate(10, sample(30:100, 7, replace = TRUE))
))

names(data) <- c(sprintf("var1_%02d", 1:10), sprintf("var2_%02d", 1:10))

data
#   var1_01 var1_02 var1_03 var1_04 var1_05 var1_06 var1_07 var1_08 var1_09 var1_10 var2_01 var2_02 var2_03 var2_04 var2_05 var2_06 var2_07 var2_08 var2_09 var2_10
# 1       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      61      72      74      58      85      93      85      46      99      55
# 2       1       1       0       1       0       0       0       1       1       0      66      56      91      72      77      53      61      34      57      43
# 3       0       0       1       1       1       1       0       1       1       1      71      89      49      99      38      84      53      41      95      64
# 4       0       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1       1      50      91      83      61      81      41      71      83      96      81
# 5       1       0       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       1      41      61      79      67      96      98      97      60      36      90
# 6       0       0       0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1      60      93      39      86      53      82      69      39      67      54
# 7       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       1       1       0      57      96      82      47      95      41     100      53      98      45
```

This is the code I want to reduce:

```
data %<>%
  mutate(var3_01 = case_when(var1_01 == 1 ~ var2_01 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_02 = case_when(var1_02 == 1 ~ var2_02 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_03 = case_when(var1_03 == 1 ~ var2_03 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_04 = case_when(var1_04 == 1 ~ var2_04 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_05 = case_when(var1_05 == 1 ~ var2_05 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_06 = case_when(var1_06 == 1 ~ var2_06 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_07 = case_when(var1_07 == 1 ~ var2_07 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_08 = case_when(var1_08 == 1 ~ var2_08 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_09 = case_when(var1_09 == 1 ~ var2_09 + 0, TRUE ~ 0),
         var3_10 = case_when(var1_10 == 1 ~ var2_10 + 0, TRUE ~ 0))
```

The goal is that if the `var1_*` == 1, it takes the value of `var2_*` for each row. However, I have not been able to replicate this code in a shorter version (`tidyverse` or `base` version doesn't matter). I tried this:

```
numbers <- c(paste0("0", 1:5))

data %<>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var1_"), ~ifelse(isTRUE(.x==1), .x:=data[, 6:10], 0), .names="var3_{numbers}"))
```

But this code does not generate the same result as the extended version. I appreciate any suggestion!

EDIT:
Thank you all for your suggestions and for editing the reproducible example. I WAS ABLE TO SOLVE MY DOUBTS and I learned a lot with your answers.
Best wishes to all!

Comment: Thank you very much, your editing allowed me to learn more. Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Staying within tidyverse

You can use `across`, using `get` to use within `case_when` to relieve us from repetition.

```
cols = names(data)[1:10]

data |> 
  mutate(across({cols}, \(x){
    ifelse(x == 1, get(sub("var1", "var2", cur_column())), 0)
    }, .names = "{sub('var1', 'var3', .col)}"))
```

```
  var1_01 var1_02 var1_03 var1_04 var1_05 var1_06 var1_07 var1_08 var1_09 var1_10 var2_01 var2_02 var2_03 var2_04
1       0       0       1       1       1       0       0       1       1       1      31      74      42      60
2       0       1       0       0       1       0       1       0       1       1      92      63      57      98
3       1       1       0       1       0       0       0       1       1       0      53      89      64      42
4       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       1       1       1      55      37      41      97
5       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       1      47      87      56      60
6       0       0       1       0       1       0       0       0       0       1      99      73      79      31
7       1       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       1       0      61      44      52      90
  var2_05 var2_06 var2_07 var2_08 var2_09 var2_10 var3_01 var3_02 var3_03 var3_04 var3_05 var3_06 var3_07 var3_08
1      60      55      57      67      97      40       0       0      42      60      60       0       0      67
2      97      78      74      30      90      49       0      63       0       0      97       0      74       0
3      77      43      52      84      43      78      53      89       0      42       0       0       0      84
4      95      94      65      86      32      82       0      37       0       0       0      94       0      86
5      47      65     100      70      91      40       0       0       0       0      47      65       0       0
6      93      77      92      57      76      93       0       0      79       0      93       0       0       0
7      46     100      74      35      38      56      61       0       0      90       0       0       0      35
  var3_09 var3_10
1      97      40
2      90      49
3      43       0
4      32      82
5       0      40
6       0      93
7      38       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solutions have allowed me to learn a lot more and I was able to solve my doubts! Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

###### Solution 1

Multiplying `across(contains("var1"))` and `across(contains("var2"))` together:

```r
sol1 <- data %>%
  mutate(across(contains("var1"), ~ .x == 1, .names = "{sub('var1', 'var3', .col)}") *
         across(contains("var2")))
```

###### Solution 2

Using `cur_column()` inside `across` to match `var1_*` and `var2_*`:

```r
sol2 <- data %>%
  mutate(across(contains("var1"),
                ~ ifelse(.x == 1, pick(everything())[[sub('var1', 'var2', cur_column())]], 0),
                .names = "{sub('var1', 'var3', .col)}"))
```

###### Solution 3

Assume that all column names are sorted well, you can use `across` to select and rename columns, convert the subset dataframe into a matrix, and pass it into `ifelse`.

```r
sol3 <- data %>%
  mutate(as_tibble(
    ifelse(as.matrix(across(contains("var1"), .names = "{sub('var1', 'var3', .col)}")) == 1,
           as.matrix(across(contains("var2"))), 0)
  ))
```

---

```r
all.equal(sol1, sol2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(sol2, sol3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solutions allowed me to learn much more. Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to maintain the wide data format, I would use matrices. Something like this:

```
set.seed(2023)
DF <- do.call(data.frame, 
              c(setNames(replicate(10, sample(0:1, 7, replace=T), simplify = FALSE),
                         sprintf("var1_%02d", 1:10)),
                setNames(replicate(10, sample(30:100, 7, replace=T), simplify = FALSE),
                         sprintf("var2_%02d", 1:10))))
foo <- function(a, b) {
  a <- as.matrix(a)
  b <- as.matrix(b)
  b[a == 0] <- 0
  colnames(b) <- gsub("var2", "var3", colnames(b))
  as.data.frame(b)
}

DF <- cbind(DF, foo(DF[, grepl("var1", names(DF))],    
                    DF[, grepl("var2", names(DF))]))

all.equal(data, DF)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, new approach, new learning for me :D Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to first make your data [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) (i.e. make it more vertical/longer/less wide)

```
data_long <- data %>% 
  mutate(.before = 1, record_id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -record_id, names_to = c("var", "j"), names_sep = "_", values_to = "value") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value)
```

Which gives the following:

```
# A tibble: 70 x 4
   record_id j      var1  var2
       <int> <chr> <int> <int>
 1         1 01        1    78
 2         1 02        0    33
 3         1 03        1    77
 4         1 04        0    80
 5         1 05        0   100
 6         1 06        1    36
 7         1 07        0    91
 8         1 08        0    39
 9         1 09        0    65
10         1 10        0    88
```

Then the implementation is straightforward:

```
data_long = data_long %>% mutate(var3 = if_else(var1==1L, var2, 0L))
```

Finally, if you really need the output to be wide:

```
data_long %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = record_id, names_from = j, values_from = var1:var3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I will take into account to create data in tidy format in the future :D Greetings!